# Caffe: How to check accuracies of multiple Data sets with already trained model at a time?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

After training LeNet model in Caffe framework using 10k images with 2 categories, I got the model lenet_iter_4000.caffemodel which contains weights and biases. I want to check the accuracy of 5k new test images(which are not part of testing images while training) at a time.I created lmdb file for all these 5k images. I know how to test the images using the following.

```
./build/tools/caffe test --model=examples/mnist/lenet_train_test.prototxt --weights=examples/mnist/lenet_iter_4000.caffemodel
```

But I am not able to get accuracy at a time like while training we will get accuracy if we put test_interval `3000`, we will get the accuracy of all testing images after `3000` iterations. If I want to test accuracy at a time after training where I have to do changes in prototxt.
My question is: how to get accuracies for multiple data sets after training using trained model?

Answer (score 4):

One fast solution is to **get accuracies for multiple Data sets while training**. You can achieve this by modifying your solver.prototxt and net.prototxt like the following, which more specifically is to use multiple "test_state" in solver.prototxt and multiple Data layers with different "include: {stage: "xxx"}" in net.prototxt for testing of muliple Data sets:

solver.prototxt:

```
net: "lenet_train_test.prototxt"
#testing stage for your orininal test images
test_state: { stage: "original test" }
#testing stage for your new test images
test_state: { stage: "new 5k test" }
#iterations for original testing
test_iter: xxx
#iterations for your new 5k testing
test_iter: xxx
#Those 2 testings use the same test_interval
test_interval: 500
```

Corresponding net.prototxt:

```
name: "LeNet"
layer {
  name: "mnist"
  type: "Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  transform_param {
    scale: 0.00390625
  }
  data_param {
    source: "examples/mnist/mnist_train_lmdb"
    batch_size: 32
    backend: LMDB
    shuffle: true
  }
}
layer {
  name: "mnist"
  type: "Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TEST
    stage: "original test"
  }
  transform_param {
    scale: 0.00390625
  }
  data_param {
    source: "examples/mnist/mnist_test_lmdb"
    batch_size: 100
    backend: LMDB
  }
}
layer {
  name: "mnist"
  type: "Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TEST
    stage: "new 5k test"
  }
  transform_param {
    scale: 0.00390625
  }
  data_param {
    source: "path/to/your/5k_images_test_lmdb"
    batch_size: 100
    backend: LMDB
  }
}
.
.
.
layer {
  name: "accuracy"
  type: "Accuracy"
  bottom: "ip2"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "accuracy"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
}
layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "SoftmaxWithLoss"
  bottom: "ip2"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "loss"
}
```

And use them like a way of finetune:

```
./build/tools/caffe train --solver=examples/mnist/solver.prototxt --weights=examples/mnist/lenet_iter_4000.caffemodel
```

At iteration 0, the solver will test the multiple Data sets and you will get the multiple accuracies of them and then can stop the solver.

Comment: I want to get accuracies for multiple Data sets after training using trained model.

Comment: A quick solution for your problem can be like this:  /build/tools/caffe train --solver=examples/mnist/lenet_solver.prototxt --weights=examples/mnist/lenet_iter_4000.caffemodel. The lenet_solver.prototxt and corresponding net.prototxt should be modified like those in my answer.

Comment: I understood but i have already trained model for hours.I want to use that model for testing purpose, in order to save time .I have given example for LeNet.But i have trained AlexNet model for 1 day.I want to use trained Alexnet model for testing .

Comment: At iteration 0, the solver will test your 2 data sets including your 5k images, and you will get their accuracies. And then you can stop it. This is the quickest method I can think of. Otherwise, you shall modify test() function in the caffe.cpp like what Solver<Dtype>::Init() do to maintain multiple nets for testing which will be a little trivial. @BHAV247

Comment: The solution of Alexnet model for testing is the same as lenet, just by modiying the sovler.prototxt by adding "test_state" and alexnet.prototxt by adding one more Data layer for your 5k testing images. The testing time is not long at all. @BHAV247

Comment: Yeah..It is one of the way..like fine-tuning .It's working.

Comment: Yes, it's a way of finetune and is the most convenient way. @BHAV247

Answer (score 0):

Just use the test tool of caffe, check [the interface examples](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/interfaces.html)

I am here a bit late but those of you wondering how to use trained model only for testing purposes can use the test tool of caffe. If you trained your model, and was planning to use it after, you should have saved the weights at each iteration. Let's name the final saved weights model_iter_xxxx.caffemodel.

1. Copy your model into a model_test.prototxt (for example)
2. Add layers to be considered in the test phase i.e input layer for testing data and accuracy layer.
3. Run: `caffe test -model path/to/model_test.prototxt -weights path/to/model_iter_xxxx.caffemodel -iterations 100`